# What is the significance of the blue French horn in How I Met Your Mother?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In  episodes **Come On**, **Twin Beds**, Ted has been seen with a blue French horn.

What does it signify?

Comment: Please elobrate the question.

Comment: It seems most part of question , is updated from Wikia link provided by me in answer. if yes, its good to mention the link. But that link also answer your question :-). Now, its irony

Comment: @Panther : I actually took took the reference from your answer only i have seen the blue honk at many places but in spite of searching each and every episode while i was referring your answer and wiki i got the reference and i put my answer,is that problematic if yes then sorry i did that.

Comment: No actually we should give credit to source (same reason i put link in answers) as we copying material from Wikia or Wikipedia or any other site as they may have copyright and its their creationin. Same like someone copy our post on other site take credit  we will feel betrayed. Check related [Meta discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/752/use-of-copied-content)

Comment: ok, from next time i will keep this in mind.Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

Excerpt from [Wikia](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_French_Horn), you can check this link for more details

> The Blue French Horn first appeared in the Pilot episode, in which Ted steals it for Robin after she saw it in a restaurant called "Carmichaels" and he said it reminded him of a 'Smurf penis' and she said she'd like one for her apartment. From this point onwards, Robin kept in on the mantle in her apartment.
>
> In the final episode, the last shot of the series is Ted holding it for Robin once again outside her door.

Basically, it's a crazy thing that Ted did for Robin on their first date and proposed at the same time. That's why when he starts to feel the same rush for her, he tried to get  out of his way to get the blue French horn.

It symbolizes that crazy stupid love from their first date.

Answer (score 1):

> The blue French horn represents Ted actively pursuing and doing anything for love. He seeks out Robin throughout the entire series, just as he repeatedly goes out of his way to get the blue French horn. He didn't stumble upon the blue French horn; he went after it. The horn also represents permanence—Ted ultimately gets it back at the end of the series despite having lost it earlier. He can always go back to the horn, as he can always go back to Robin.

[More](http://www.quora.com/How-I-Met-Your-Mother-TV-series/What-does-the-blue-french-horn-symbolize)

Comment: Have you took this answer from quora (http://www.quora.com/How-I-Met-Your-Mother-TV-series/What-does-the-blue-french-horn-symbolize), if yes then its good to mention the source.

Comment: @Panther Refer respective meta question, [Use of copied content](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/752/use-of-copied-content)

Comment: Not only are you supposed to give proper reference when quoting an entire textblock as a whole, you should put it in proper quote blocks to make it clear to everyone that those aren't your words.

Comment: And by the way, you also don't need to create a second account just to answer your own question. And if you do, please make sure to not do any mutual voting between the two accounts, everything else would be vote fraud. If you are indeed the same person like the asker, we'd encourage you to merge your accounts using the [procedure described in the help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).